# Displaying count of notifications Codeigniter Json

Tags: json, codeigniter, notifications

Hi I do not usually develop in json or ajax but I think I need it to achieve a task.

I have a notification table which contains all the notifications per user, my question is how do I display the notification count on my web page?

I tried doing some sort of notification script using Json and when I go to the webpage it actually sees the updated count but does not display is.

Please see code attached including screen shots of what I have.

I do appreciate your help.

**Model**

```
public function get_notification($recipient = null){
            $session = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('notifications');
            $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = notifications.user_id');
            $this->db->where(array('notifications.recipient' => $recipient));
            $query = $this->db->get();  
            return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function index($user_id = null)
    {

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data['notification_count'] = $this->Notification_model->get_notification_count($user_id);
        $data['entries'] = $this->Music_model->getlimit_entries();
        $data['videos'] = $this->Video_model->getlimit_entries();
        $data['artists'] = $this->Artist_model->getlimit_entries();
        //$data['users'] = $this->User_model->get_user();



        //$data['title'] = 'Home';
        $this->load->view('user/templates/header_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/home_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/templates/footer_view');



    }
```

**View**

```
                <li>
                    <a href="profile.html">
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <?php echo $notification_count." New Follwers";?>
                            <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Notification JS

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() { get_notifications(); }, 2500);

```
    function get_notifications()
    {

     $.post(base_url +"user/home/index", { notification_count : notification_count}, function(data) {

     if (data.status == 'ok')
     {

        var current_content = $("#alert_id").html();


        $("#alert_id").html(current_content + data.content);

     }
     else
     {
    //there was an error do something 

     }

     }, "json");

}

    get_notifications();
```

});

[Notification screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPYTU.png)

Comment: Sorry the view given above is wrong, this is the right one.

Comment: <?php
                        if($notification_count):
                        ?>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle count-info" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>  <span class="label label-warning" id="alert_id"><?php echo $notification_count;?></span>
                    </a>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your JS code (if it's ok or should be updated too), but I believe that in your Controller you should edit this line:

> $data['notification_count'] = $this->Notification_model->get_notification_count($user_id);

to

> $data['notification_count'] = count($this->Notification_model->get_notification($user_id));

**Update**
Btw, I don't think it's the best way to manage your code..
I guess you should have something like this:

```
$notifications = $this->Notification_model->get_notification($user_id);
/** some code to work with notifications bodies/strings **/
$data['notification_count'] = count($notifications);
```

The upper answer was just fast showing where you may have a mistake. Hope it helps.